# How to get values from text area from ejs. Bootstrap, Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, ejs

I have a Bootstrap forms in my "EJS" file and "SAVE" button on the bottom.
When i press "SAVE", i want to store data from fields to my DB.

The problem is that in the function which executes on post - "req.body" is empty.
So there is a logical problem, but i can't get what is exactly.

Here is my code:

EJS

```
<div id = "container">
    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post">
       <div class="form-group">
           <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">First Name</label>
           <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputFirstName3" placeholder= <%= user.profile.name %> >
           </div>
       </div>
       .
       .
       .
       <div class="form-group">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
       </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

APP.JS

```
app.get("/edit", permissions.requireActiveRole, edituserprofile.editMyProfile);

app.post("/edit", permissions.requireActiveRole, edituserprofile.saveChanges);
```

saveChanges() function in separate JS file

```
exports.saveChanges = function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.body); ////  logs {}, data from ejs fields should be here!
}
```

I hope my question is clear, Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `<input>`'s need `name` attributes:

```
<input type="text" name="firstName" class="form-control" id="inputFirstName3" placeholder= <%= user.profile.name %> >
```

I would also put quotes around any expanded variables, by the way.